# How to increase the size around text in \psframebox

Tags: pstricks, boxes

when using `\psframebox` the size between text and corners of the box is really small. 
Is there a way to increase that?

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[dvips]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\psset{linewidth=1pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(10,10)
        \psset{cornersize=absolute,linearc=0.15}
    \rput(6.5,4){\psframebox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white]{\Large{TEST}}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white` are not needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include the option `framesep=<len>` where `<len>` is any (PStricks) length. Default is `3pt`.

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvips]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\psset{linewidth=1pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(10,10)
        \psset{cornersize=absolute,linearc=0.15}
        \rput(6.5,4){\psframebox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white]{\Large{TEST}}}
        \rput(6.5,0){\psframebox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white, framesep=20pt]{\Large{TEST}}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: You beat me by seconds!

Comment: `framesep=<len>` len is not a TeX length it is a PSTricks length which is far different.